# PHP formatting a text file

Tags: php, text, formatting

How can I format a text file that the content looks like this:

```
Col 1     Col 2     Col 3    ...
abcd      ab        a
ab        a         abcd
```

Each string have a different length.

The output I have reached with my PHP code looks quite ugly:

```
Col 1     Col 2     Col 3    ...
abc   abc   abc
abc      abc        abc
```

My PHP code to create the text file follows:

```
$tab = "\t\t";
$txtString = "";
foreach ($teams->get() as $team) {
    $class = $classes->getClasses($team["class_id"]);
    $club = $clubs->get($team["club_number"]);
    $txtString .= $class[0]["class_name"] . $tab;
    $txtString .= $team["club_number"] . " " . $club[0]["name"] . $team["team_number"] . $tab;
    $txtString .= $team["team_leader_name"] . $tab;
    $txtString .= $team["team_leader_street"] . $tab;
    $txtString .= $team["team_leader_place"] . $tab;
    $txtString .= $team["team_leader_phone"] . "\n";
}

$file = "Mannschaftsfuehrer.txt";
file_put_contents($file, $txtString);
```

Can anyone help me to get a well formatted text file?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please reduce your code to a [short, self-contained example](http://sscce.org).

Comment: You'd need to detect what the longest string is for every column for every record, then use that as your spacing guide. Which basically means two passes through the text. one to detect sizes, one to actually do the formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you compare with sprintf execution time is quite low.& spaces can be changed. SO i prefer using my own function.

Here is a function which returns you string with enough spaces.
Here str is string you want to format.

```
 function getFormatted($str,$col_width){
  $n=$col_width-strlen($str);
  for(;$n>0;$n--)
  $str.=' ';
  return $str;
}
```

Comment: Use this function - is bad idea. The beautiful solution of this problem: use `sprintf` function with offset formatting.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pad with spaces, and for that use sprintf:

```
sprintf("10%s", "string" ); // "string" has a length of 6, and so, first 4 characters will be " "( space );
```

sprintf documentation:
http://www.php.net/manual/ro/function.sprintf.php

> (PHP 4, PHP 5) sprintf — Return a formatted string